# Do I need to resubmit my sitemap after updating it?

Tags: sitemap

I made some updates in my sitemap, when I first submitted it all the links are like this 
http://www.www.bagreviewsguru.com/

and I changed it to
http://www.bagreviewsguru.com/

because there are warnings saying that urls are not accesible due to double www. So I need to resubmit it to Google Search Console?

Answer (score 0):

It may speed up things according this blog post: http://www.lauradhamilton.com/resubmitting-your-sitemap-to-google. However, it's not something guaranteed.